# How to change values of columns in Pandas Data Frame using modified function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, function

How to modify below function so as to be able to add Data Frame as a parameter and convert all values in Data Frame which are in "strange" to values whioch are in "ascii_replacements" ? In Python Pandas ?

I ask you about it because I have many values in my Data Frame which are identical like in "strange" and I need to change it but I do not know how?

```
def removeAccents(input_text):

    strange='ŮôῡΒძěἊἦëĐᾇόἶἧзвŅῑἼźἓŉἐÿἈΌἢὶЁϋυŕŽŎŃğûλВὦėἜŤŨîᾪĝžἙâᾣÚκὔჯᾏᾢĠфĞὝŲŊŁČῐЙῤŌὭŏყἀхῦЧĎὍОуνἱῺèᾒῘᾘὨШūლἚύсÁóĒἍŷöὄЗὤἥბĔõὅῥŋБщἝξĢюᾫაπჟῸდΓÕűřἅгἰშΨńģὌΥÒᾬÏἴქὀῖὣᾙῶŠὟὁἵÖἕΕῨčᾈķЭτἻůᾕἫжΩᾶŇᾁἣჩαἄἹΖеУŹἃἠᾞåᾄГΠКíōĪὮϊὂᾱიżŦИὙἮὖÛĮἳφᾖἋΎΰῩŚἷРῈĲἁéὃσňİΙῠΚĸὛΪᾝᾯψÄᾭêὠÀღЫĩĈμΆᾌἨÑἑïოĵÃŒŸζჭᾼőΣŻçųøΤΑËņĭῙŘАдὗპŰἤცᾓήἯΐÎეὊὼΘЖᾜὢĚἩħĂыῳὧďТΗἺĬὰὡὬὫÇЩᾧñῢĻᾅÆßшδòÂчῌᾃΉᾑΦÍīМƒÜἒĴἿťᾴĶÊΊȘῃΟúχΔὋŴćŔῴῆЦЮΝΛῪŢὯнῬũãáἽĕᾗნᾳἆᾥйᾡὒსᾎĆрĀüСὕÅýფᾺῲšŵкἎἇὑЛვёἂΏθĘэᾋΧĉᾐĤὐὴιăąäὺÈФĺῇἘſგŜæῼῄĊἏØÉПяწДĿᾮἭĜХῂᾦωთĦлðὩზკίᾂᾆἪпἸиᾠώᾀŪāоÙἉἾρаđἌΞļÔβĖÝᾔĨНŀęᾤÓцЕĽŞὈÞუтΈέıàᾍἛśìŶŬȚĳῧῊᾟάεŖᾨᾉςΡმᾊᾸįᾚὥηᾛġÐὓłγľмþᾹἲἔбċῗჰხοἬŗŐἡὲῷῚΫŭᾩὸùᾷĹēრЯĄὉὪῒᾲΜᾰÌœĥტ'

 
    ascii_replacements='UoyBdeAieDaoiiZVNiIzeneyAOiiEyyrZONgulVoeETUiOgzEaoUkyjAoGFGYUNLCiIrOOoqaKyCDOOUniOeiIIOSulEySAoEAyooZoibEoornBSEkGYOapzOdGOuraGisPngOYOOIikoioIoSYoiOeEYcAkEtIuiIZOaNaicaaIZEUZaiIaaGPKioIOioaizTIYIyUIifiAYyYSiREIaeosnIIyKkYIIOpAOeoAgYiCmAAINeiojAOYzcAoSZcuoTAEniIRADypUitiiIiIeOoTZIoEIhAYoodTIIIaoOOCSonyKaAsSdoACIaIiFIiMfUeJItaKEISiOuxDOWcRoiTYNLYTONRuaaIeinaaoIoysACRAuSyAypAoswKAayLvEaOtEEAXciHyiiaaayEFliEsgSaOiCAOEPYtDKOIGKiootHLdOzkiaaIPIIooaUaOUAIrAdAKlObEYiINleoOTEKSOTuTEeiaAEsiYUTiyIIaeROAsRmAAiIoiIgDylglMtAieBcihkoIrOieoIYuOouaKerYAOOiaMaIoht'


    translator=str.maketrans(strange,ascii_replacements)
    
    
    return input_text.translate(translator)
```

Comment: please should provide the input you have and the desired output you want, please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have simulated a data frame to deomostrate
- there is no need to refactor your function,  just call it with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
import numpy as np

def removeAccents(input_text):
    strange = "ŮôῡΒძěἊἦëĐᾇόἶἧзвŅῑἼźἓŉἐÿἈΌἢὶЁϋυŕŽŎŃğûλВὦėἜŤŨîᾪĝžἙâᾣÚκὔჯᾏᾢĠфĞὝŲŊŁČῐЙῤŌὭŏყἀхῦЧĎὍОуνἱῺèᾒῘᾘὨШūლἚύсÁóĒἍŷöὄЗὤἥბĔõὅῥŋБщἝξĢюᾫაπჟῸდΓÕűřἅгἰშΨńģὌΥÒᾬÏἴქὀῖὣᾙῶŠὟὁἵÖἕΕῨčᾈķЭτἻůᾕἫжΩᾶŇᾁἣჩαἄἹΖеУŹἃἠᾞåᾄГΠКíōĪὮϊὂᾱიżŦИὙἮὖÛĮἳφᾖἋΎΰῩŚἷРῈĲἁéὃσňİΙῠΚĸὛΪᾝᾯψÄᾭêὠÀღЫĩĈμΆᾌἨÑἑïოĵÃŒŸζჭᾼőΣŻçųøΤΑËņĭῙŘАдὗპŰἤცᾓήἯΐÎეὊὼΘЖᾜὢĚἩħĂыῳὧďТΗἺĬὰὡὬὫÇЩᾧñῢĻᾅÆßшδòÂчῌᾃΉᾑΦÍīМƒÜἒĴἿťᾴĶÊΊȘῃΟúχΔὋŴćŔῴῆЦЮΝΛῪŢὯнῬũãáἽĕᾗნᾳἆᾥйᾡὒსᾎĆрĀüСὕÅýფᾺῲšŵкἎἇὑЛვёἂΏθĘэᾋΧĉᾐĤὐὴιăąäὺÈФĺῇἘſგŜæῼῄĊἏØÉПяწДĿᾮἭĜХῂᾦωთĦлðὩზკίᾂᾆἪпἸиᾠώᾀŪāоÙἉἾρаđἌΞļÔβĖÝᾔĨНŀęᾤÓцЕĽŞὈÞუтΈέıàᾍἛśìŶŬȚĳῧῊᾟάεŖᾨᾉςΡმᾊᾸįᾚὥηᾛġÐὓłγľмþᾹἲἔбċῗჰხοἬŗŐἡὲῷῚΫŭᾩὸùᾷĹēრЯĄὉὪῒᾲΜᾰÌœĥტ"
    ascii_replacements = "UoyBdeAieDaoiiZVNiIzeneyAOiiEyyrZONgulVoeETUiOgzEaoUkyjAoGFGYUNLCiIrOOoqaKyCDOOUniOeiIIOSulEySAoEAyooZoibEoornBSEkGYOapzOdGOuraGisPngOYOOIikoioIoSYoiOeEYcAkEtIuiIZOaNaicaaIZEUZaiIaaGPKioIOioaizTIYIyUIifiAYyYSiREIaeosnIIyKkYIIOpAOeoAgYiCmAAINeiojAOYzcAoSZcuoTAEniIRADypUitiiIiIeOoTZIoEIhAYoodTIIIaoOOCSonyKaAsSdoACIaIiFIiMfUeJItaKEISiOuxDOWcRoiTYNLYTONRuaaIeinaaoIoysACRAuSyAypAoswKAayLvEaOtEEAXciHyiiaaayEFliEsgSaOiCAOEPYtDKOIGKiootHLdOzkiaaIPIIooaUaOUAIrAdAKlObEYiINleoOTEKSOTuTEeiaAEsiYUTiyIIaeROAsRmAAiIoiIgDylglMtAieBcihkoIrOieoIYuOouaKerYAOOiaMaIoht"
    translator = str.maketrans(strange, ascii_replacements)
    return input_text.translate(translator)


strange = "ŮôῡΒძěἊἦëĐᾇόἶἧзвŅῑἼźἓŉἐÿἈΌἢὶЁϋυŕŽŎŃğûλВὦėἜŤŨîᾪĝžἙâᾣÚκὔჯᾏᾢĠфĞὝŲŊŁČῐЙῤŌὭŏყἀхῦЧĎὍОуνἱῺèᾒῘᾘὨШūლἚύсÁóĒἍŷöὄЗὤἥბĔõὅῥŋБщἝξĢюᾫაπჟῸდΓÕűřἅгἰშΨńģὌΥÒᾬÏἴქὀῖὣᾙῶŠὟὁἵÖἕΕῨčᾈķЭτἻůᾕἫжΩᾶŇᾁἣჩαἄἹΖеУŹἃἠᾞåᾄГΠКíōĪὮϊὂᾱიżŦИὙἮὖÛĮἳφᾖἋΎΰῩŚἷРῈĲἁéὃσňİΙῠΚĸὛΪᾝᾯψÄᾭêὠÀღЫĩĈμΆᾌἨÑἑïოĵÃŒŸζჭᾼőΣŻçųøΤΑËņĭῙŘАдὗპŰἤცᾓήἯΐÎეὊὼΘЖᾜὢĚἩħĂыῳὧďТΗἺĬὰὡὬὫÇЩᾧñῢĻᾅÆßшδòÂчῌᾃΉᾑΦÍīМƒÜἒĴἿťᾴĶÊΊȘῃΟúχΔὋŴćŔῴῆЦЮΝΛῪŢὯнῬũãáἽĕᾗნᾳἆᾥйᾡὒსᾎĆрĀüСὕÅýფᾺῲšŵкἎἇὑЛვёἂΏθĘэᾋΧĉᾐĤὐὴιăąäὺÈФĺῇἘſგŜæῼῄĊἏØÉПяწДĿᾮἭĜХῂᾦωთĦлðὩზკίᾂᾆἪпἸиᾠώᾀŪāоÙἉἾρаđἌΞļÔβĖÝᾔĨНŀęᾤÓцЕĽŞὈÞუтΈέıàᾍἛśìŶŬȚĳῧῊᾟάεŖᾨᾉςΡმᾊᾸįᾚὥηᾛġÐὓłγľмþᾹἲἔбċῗჰხοἬŗŐἡὲῷῚΫŭᾩὸùᾷĹēრЯĄὉὪῒᾲΜᾰÌœĥტ"


df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["".join(np.random.choice(list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 3)) + " "
                           + np.random.choice(list(strange), 1)[0]
                           for i in range(15) ]})

df["col2"] = df["col"].apply(removeAccents)
df
```

|  | col | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | chm Ģ | chm G |
| 1 | xjk М | xjk M |
| 2 | kyw α | kyw a |
| 3 | usd ᾄ | usd a |
| 4 | vxg ς | vxg s |
| 5 | jcm ũ | jcm u |
| 6 | uya Ĩ | uya I |
| 7 | udr გ | udr g |
| 8 | whp ῴ | whp o |
| 9 | crr Т | crr T |
| 10 | djd Ὧ | djd O |
| 11 | ubn ქ | ubn k |
| 12 | huq ὤ | huq o |
| 13 | van Ÿ | van Y |
| 14 | dbp ბ | dbp b |